# Create resizable window with fixed top coordinate

Tags: c++, winapi, window, hwnd

I'd like to implemented a window that its top coordinate is always *X* (for simplicity let's say 0). Meaning, the window's top side is fixed on 0 which is the top of the screen.

I've already implemented the window, set its position using [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) but I'm struggling maintaining  its top coordinate value.

Comment: Is this for a child window? If you show what you have already done it would be easier to understand.

Comment: Just a simple exe the create a window using `CreateWindowEx`. alot of utility classes are involved in the window creation so it's hard to post all the relevant code. I'm hopefully looking for a simple way of manipulating existing `HWND` to accomplish that.

Comment: You mean you don't want the user to be able to move the window? (this requires removing the caption and implementing a custom resize) - or are you looking for `SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 0, 0, width, height, SWP_NOMOVE)` which will resize the window but it won't change the top-left corner value.

Comment: I want the user to be able to resize the window but the top side must be at the same coordinate. left, right & bottom sides may move

Comment: Is [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150504-00/?p=44944) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a window with no caption bar, for example

```
CreateWindow(className, title, WS_THICKFRAME | WS_POPUP, ...)
```

Then override `WM_NCHITTEST` to change the requests for moving the window up and down.

If window has caption bar, for example:

```
CreateWindow(className, title, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, ...)
```

Then add override for `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` as well:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {

    case WM_NCHITTEST:
    {
        LRESULT lresult = DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        switch (lresult)
        {
        case HTTOP:      lresult = HTCLIENT; break;
        case HTTOPLEFT:  lresult = HTLEFT;   break;
        case HTTOPRIGHT: lresult = HTRIGHT;  break;
        }
        return lresult;
    }

    case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
    {
        WINDOWPOS* wndpos = (WINDOWPOS*)lParam;
        wndpos->y = 100;//choose a fixed position
        break;
    }

    ...
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```